# Android repack APK problems with 7zip

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, zip, apk, 7zip

I have an Android APK developed by Unity3d, and test APK repacking via the following command lines.

1. modify the zip file via 7zip
2. resign the zip file. `jarsigner -verbose -keystore debug.keystore -signedjar file_unaligned.apk file.apk alias < pass.ini > nul`
3. zipalign the zip file. `zipalign -f 4 file_unaligned.apk file_release.apk > nul`
4. install and test the final zip file (APK file)

The problems happen in step 1, only APK generated by `7z d -tzip zipfile files-to-delete` will pass the test, adding files (`7z a`) or updating files (`7z u`) or unzip-reziping often results an install-able APK which dies after startup (no useful logcat outputs), I need to repack APK correctly, any ideas?